# Jetpack compose BlendMode.Xor different from preview

Tags: canvas, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am testing a simple `Canvas` composable using `BlendMode.Xor` option. Below is my code :

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
            ) {
                XORTest()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun XORTest() {
    Box(
        Modifier.background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), onDraw = {
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Black,
                center = this.center,
                radius = 100f,
                alpha = 0.9f
            ) 

            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Yellow,
                radius = 50f,
                center = this.center,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Xor
            )

            drawCircle(
                color = Color.White,
                radius = 50f,
                center = this.center + Offset(40f, 40f),
                blendMode = BlendMode.Xor
            )
        })
    }
}
```

This results in preview like this :

[image]

However, when I run this preview on my emulator (in both dark/light mode) it results like this:

[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

I expect the preview & the actual result to be same.

Comment: It looks like a preview bug, I suggest you [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=823947) it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will report it!